# StepScope bean duplication when using XML based bean definition

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have the following spring boot 2 setup and it throws a `BeanDefinitionOverrideException` during startup only when using `XML` based bean definition the same works while using `Java` based bean definition and while using the same XML in @ImportResource works

Note upgrading to SB3 isn't an option for now.

**Startup Error**

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The bean 'scopedTarget.reader', defined in BeanDefinition defined in file [/Users/username/IdeaProjects/testing-spring-batch/target/classes/org/example/Reader.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in file [/Users/username/IdeaProjects/testing-spring-batch/target/classes/org/example/Reader.class] and overriding is disabled.

Action:

Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

**Main.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Main.class);
        app.setSources(Collections.singleton("classpath:launch-context.xml"));
        System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(app.run(args).getParent()));
    }
}
```

**Reader.java**

```
@Component
@StepScope
public class Reader implements ItemReader<String> {
// return a list of string
}
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <batch:job id="test">
        <batch:step id="companyStep">
            <batch:tasklet>
                <batch:chunk reader="reader" processor="processor"
                             writer="writer" commit-interval="1" />
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>
</beans>
```

**Update**

I see that the step scope bean poxy `scopedTarget.reader` is registered twice in the Bean definition registry once while Spring does the auto scan of the annotation and second again when the Step Scope post processor (PP) is invoked.

While using Java based configs the Step Scope Bean PP has the auto proxy flag set to false (in `ScopeConfiguration` class), so it doesn't proxy the bean.

But while using XML based definition the StepScope is created using the native constructor (by `CoreNamespaceUtils` class' `checkForScope` method) causing the duplicate proxy to be created.

Any way to circumvent this behaviour?

**Note:**

This doesn't happen when I import the XML bean source using `@ImportResource("classpath:launch-context.xml")` as in this case beans in the imported sources are only processed when the application context is refreshed i.e, after the bean definitions are parsed.

In my case the imported resource is dynamic. So need a way to dynamically pass this resource, looking for a way to do that till the issue in the OP is understood.

Comment: just `@ImportResource(locations = {"${my_path}"})` and add my_path to application.properties

Comment: That'd work...I also have a default that I must use otherwise....but is there a way to do this programmatically?

Comment: just `@ImportResource(locations = {"${my_path:your default value}"})`

Comment: Yep got that...I could do that...but for full context I do some validations and stuff which I can still do using your idea & SPEL...but any other way to programmatically pass it though?

Comment: need one second to write the code

Answer (score 1):

- you basically finish the job, just need one more step forward.

1. add a path to application.properties

```
xml_path={a xml path like "classpath:launch-context.xml"}
```

2. then `@ImportResource(locations = {"${xml_path:a default xml path}"})`

---

- Or you can write a `DynamicXmlConfigLoader` to do it
- example code:

```
public class DynamicXmlConfigLoader implements ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar {
    @Value("xml_path")
    private static String xmlConfigPathInConfig;
    @Override
    public void registerBeanDefinitions(AnnotationMetadata importingClassMetadata, BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
        ApplicationContext context = ((AnnotationConfigApplicationContext) registry).getApplicationContext();
        String xmlConfigPath = xmlConfigPathInConfig;
        Resource resource = context.getResource(xmlConfigPath);
        XmlBeanDefinitionReader reader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(registry);
        reader.loadBeanDefinitions(resource);
        for (String beanName : registry.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
            BeanDefinition beanDefinition = registry.getBeanDefinition(beanName);
            context.getBeanFactory().registerSingleton(beanName, beanDefinition);
        }
    }
}

@Configuration
@Import(DynamicXmlConfigLoader.class)
public class AppConfig {
}
```

Comment: Looks like this is fixed as part of https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/3936. Updating to the latest version of SB 2.7.14 fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is fixed as part of [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/3936). Updating to the latest version of SB 2.7.14 fixed this.

But it hasn't been fixed for job-scoped beans though. In that case you can use `@ImportedResource` to load your XML definition & workaround this problem.

Apologies for answering own question.